# RoR API how to use the post for asociations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

I am string an API project using RoR 6. I have this models:

```
class Province < ApplicationRecord
  validates :province, presence: true, length: {minimum:5}, uniqueness: true
  has_many :cities, dependent: :destroy
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  validates :city, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}, uniqueness: true
  belongs_to :province
end
```

the migrations:

```
class CreateProvinces < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :provinces do |t|
      t.string :province

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCities < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :cities do |t|
      t.string :city
      t.references :province, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

the controller method:

```
def create
    @city = City.new(city_params)

    if @city.save
      render json: @city, status: :created, location: @city
    else
      render json: @city.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

private
    def city_params
      params.require(:city).permit(:city, :province_id)
    end
```

and the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :provinces, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :cities, defaults: { format: :json }
  end
end
```

the thing is this, when running:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/provinces/1/cities' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "city": "New City",
    "province": 1
}'
```

> { "province": [ "must exist" ] }

The province exists. But there is no way to insert it. If I use the rails console and run:

```
p=Province.find(1)
c=City.new({city: 'New City', province: p})
c.save
```

it works as expected. How to solve this?

Comment: Can you share the controller action that supports this route?

Comment: Why are you passing `"province": 1`? you have a nested route...

Comment: it keeps telling me `{ "province": [ "must exist" ]}` if I do not pass it, @max

Comment: Then you're doing something very wrong in your controller. Add it to the question.

Comment: I added it to the question already, @max. Also I would like to say I used the scaffold to generate it.

Comment: The scaffolds don't work out of the box for nested resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with a nested route you want to find the parent resource first and then create the nested resource off it:

```
class ProvincesController < ApplicationController

  # POST /provinces/1/cities
  def create
    @province = Province.find(params[:province_id])
    @city = @province.cities.new(city_params)
    
    if @city.save
      render json: @city, status: :created, location: @city
    else
      render json: @city.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
    
  private
  def city_params
    params.require(:city).permit(:city)
  end
end
```

Also calling the columns `provinces.province` and `cities.city` makes a lot less sense then using `provinces.name` and `cities.name`.